# Modular form -  Petersson operator

Tags: modular-forms

Hi,

I've a question regarding the Petersson operator.

We have the following definition and the lemma.

Definition

Let $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi: \mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

For

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix} \in \Gamma_1$ und $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & \mu \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{Z}^{2}$

we set

i) $\left( \phi|_{k,m} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{pmatrix} \right) (\tau,z) :=
      (c\tau+d)^{-k} e^{2\pi i m \frac{-cz^2}{c\tau+d}} \phi(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d},\frac{z}{c\tau+d})$ `and

ii) $( \phi|_m \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & \mu \\ \end{pmatrix}) (\tau,z) := 
      e^{2\pi i m (\lambda^2\tau + 2 \lambda z)} \phi(\tau, z + \lambda\tau+\mu) $

Lemma

Let $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi: \mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

$M, M_1, M_2 \in \Gamma_1;\; X, X_1, X_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ satisfy

i)  $(\phi|_{k,m} M_1)|_{k,m} M_2 = \phi|_{k,m} (M_1 M_2)$

ii) $(\phi|_m X_1)|_m X_2 = \phi|_m (X_1 + X_2)$

iii) $( \phi|_{k,m} M)|_m XM = (\phi|_m X)|_{k,m}M $

I've to prove that

$ \phi|(M,X)|(M',X') = \phi|(MM',XM'+X')$

Unfortunately, after spending a lot of time, I am not clear how I can prove this. The main problem is that I don't know which calculation rule I can use. The lemma only deals with one variable ($M$ or $X$) but not with 2 variables $(M,X)$.

Do you have any hints how I could proceed.

Thanks and regards,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the definition you want for $\phi|(M,X)$ is $(\phi |_{k,m} M) |_m X$.So your left hand side involving $\phi |(M,X) | (M',X')$ is the composition of four of these operators.  Then the problem isn't too bad given your (i)-(iii).

Comment: Hi Matt,

thanks a lot for your answer.

I had a similar idea, but with

$\phi|(M,X)$ is $(\phi|_m X)|_{k,m} M$

but I am not sure whether I can write it like this.

I think, I have to put i) and ii) from the definition together.
Therefore, my guess was $\phi|(M,X)$ is $(\phi|_m X)|_{k,m} M$.
However, I haven't found a calculation rule which proves that my guess goes to the right direction.

Do you have any hint?

Thanks a lot,
Jan

Comment: Actually, I want to prove, that definition defines an action of the semi direct product 
$SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$

I've already shown, that the semi direct product has the group law
$(X,M)(M',X') = (MM', XM'+X')$.

Now, I have to prove
$ \phi|(M,X)|(M',X') = \phi|(MM',XM'+X')$

If this is proven, then according to the definition of an action (
$s \circ (g_1 \circ g2) = (g_1 g_2) \circ s $), i) and ii) of the definition above jointly define an action.


Comment: Are you sure you are checking what you need to check?  Keep in mind that this is a right action just like for usual modular forms.  It looks like you are under the impression it is a left action.  Does this help?

Comment: Actually, my main problem is, that I don't know why the definition of $\phi|(M,X)$ should be $(\phi|_{k,m}M)|_m X$ (as you've written).

Do you know the rules, why this should be true?
Could you be so kind and explain a little bit how you did this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The definition is chosen so that your desired identity is true; the point is that you then get a group action of the semi-direct product of $\SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot for your patience and your help. I really appreciate it. Now things are a lot clearer to me (reading the stuff again, I realize that I made a lot of mistakes, e.g. the mistake of the left and right operation). Thanks again.